# Jboss EAP 7.1 not load Spring Boot Context/Application When package as EAR

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jboss7.x, ear

I'm having a hard time, I'm not able to generate an EAR using Maven with Spring boot.

When deploying in JBoss 7.1 EAP, jboss does not load the context/application of spring, but also does not appear any error, could you help me, by kindly already tried in several ways.

**When I perform the deploy of WAR, everything works perfectly, the problem is in the packaging of my EAR I think.**

**Main pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>Aplicação para gerenciamento de segurança</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>security-commons</module>
        <module>security-services</module>
        <module>security-ear</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <security.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</security.version>
        <version.ear.plugin>2.6</version.ear.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.6</version.war.plugin>

        <swagger.version>2.6.1</swagger.version>

        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>security-commons</artifactId>
                <version>${security.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <!-- <type>ejb</type> -->
                <scope>compile</scope> 
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>security-services</artifactId>
                <version>${security.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>

            <!-- swagger -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.10</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

WAR pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>security-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>security-services</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- swagger -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>br.com.me.security.SecurityApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>${spring.boot.version}</version> -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>2.6</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

EAR pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>security-ear</artifactId>
    <name>security-ear</name>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-services</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>br.com.me.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>security-services</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>security-services.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/security</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Update:

Deployment content:

```
C:.
└───security-ear.ear
    ├───lib
    ├───META-INF
    │   └───maven
    │       └───br.com.me.security
    │           └───security-ear
    └───security-services.war
        ├───br
        │   └───com
        │       └───me
        │           └───security
        │               ├───infra
        │               │   └───config
        │               └───web
        ├───META-INF
        │   └───maven
        │       └───br.com.me.security
        │           └───security-services
        └───WEB-INF
            └───lib
                └───security-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
                    └───META-INF
                        └───maven
                            └───br.com.me.security
                                └───security-commons
```

My application class:

```
//@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
/*@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="br.com.me.security")
@EnableAutoConfiguration*/
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecurityApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {


    private static final Class<SecurityApplication> applicationClass = SecurityApplication.class;


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
        System.out.println("Up here test");
        return app.sources(SecurityApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


    }

/*  @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/*"); // required JBOSS EAP 6 / AS 7
        super.onStartup(container);
    }*/
}
```

File jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/security</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

File jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/security</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Thank you for your time and attention!!

Comment: What is the ear content? The war inside deploys fine?

Comment: @DanielJipa I updated the question, but I think my WAR is right, when I perform deploy only from WAR file, it works perfectly on JBOSS